# Regex or standard substring solution to remove Wordpress image sizing from filename

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I need to remove the Wordpress width and height details from an image path using Javascript, rather than pulling it from the full image. E.g:

```
imagePath = "http://localhost:8888/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/P1010050-700x525.jpg"
```

I need to convert `imagePath` into `imagePath = "http://localhost:8888/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/P1010050.jpg"`

It is not always the same path, and not always a jpg, but it will always be `-123x123` that needs to be removed.

Am I better off doing a regex expression for this (and if so, what pattern do I need?) or should I take the end after the last `-` off, and then take the file extension off, and then reconstruct the string with concatenation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `String.prototype.replace()` function with specific regex pattern:

```js
var imagePath = "http://localhost:8888/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/P1010050-700x525.jpg",
    replaced = imagePath.replace(/\-[^-]+(\.\w+)$/, '$1');

console.log(replaced);
```